# Zabbix with Traefik Proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, web-hosting, zabbix, zabbix-agent, traefik

i am currently setting up a Zabbix Environment for IT Monitoring. Zabbix is running behind a Traefik V2(.10.5) Proxy.

There are two Domains in use: `inframon.***.local` for the Frontend and `agent-ep.inframon.***.local` for the Active Check Endpoint.

I can't get the active Checks to work. Passive are working fine. But i'd rather use active tbh.

For the frontend, this is the Traefik Dynamic Config:

```
# services/Zabbix.toml
[http.services]
        [http.services.ZabbixFrontend.loadBalancer]
                [[http.services.ZabbixFrontend.loadBalancer.servers]]
                        url = "http://ZabbixFrontend:8080"

# routers/Zabbix.toml
[http.routers]
    [http.routers.ZabbixFrontend]
        entryPoints = ["WebSecure"]
        rule = "Host(`inframon.***.local`)"
        service = "ZabbixFrontend"
        tls = true
        middlewares = []
           
[[tls.certificates]]
    certFile = "/etc/certs/Zabbix/Zabbix.crt"
    keyFile = "/etc/certs/Zabbix/Zabbix.key"
```

This works perfectly fine.

Now, this is the Dynamic Config for the TCP Route/Service for the Active Check Agent Endpoint (to Port 10051)

```
# service/ZabbixAgent.toml
[tcp.services]
    [tcp.services.ZabbixAgentEP.loadBalancer]
        [[tcp.services.ZabbixAgentEP.loadBalancer.servers]]
            url = "ZabbixServer:10051"

# routers/ZabbixAgent.toml
[tcp.routers]
    [tcp.routers.ZabbixAgentEP]
        entryPoints = ["ZabbixAgentEP"]
        rule = "HostSNI(`agent-ep.inframon.***.local`)"
        service = "ZabbixAgentEP"
        tls = true
   
[[tls.certificates]]
    certFile = "/etc/certs/ZabbixAgentEP/ZabbixAgentEP.crt"
    keyFile = "/etc/certs/ZabbixAgentEP/ZabbixAgentEP.key"
```

The SSL/TLS Certificates used are created using the Companies internal CA.

This is the Agent Config File:

```
SourceIP=<MachineIP>
Server=<ZabbixHostIP>,inframon.***.local,agent-ep.inframon.***.local
ListenIP=<MachineIP>
ServerActive=agent-ep.inframon.***.local
Hostname=TestMachine
```

and now, whenever i start the Agent, if get the following Response (from log file)

```
 # systemctl restart zabbix-agent ; tail -f /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log
323155:20231027:123659.542 IPv6 support:          YES
323155:20231027:123659.542 TLS support:           YES
323155:20231027:123659.542 **************************
323155:20231027:123659.542 using configuration file: /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
323155:20231027:123659.542 agent #0 started [main process]
323156:20231027:123659.543 agent #1 started [collector]
323157:20231027:123659.543 agent #2 started [listener #1]
323158:20231027:123659.543 agent #3 started [listener #2]
323159:20231027:123659.544 agent #4 started [listener #3]
323160:20231027:123659.544 agent #5 started [active checks #1]
323160:20231027:123705.547 Unable to receive from [agent-ep.inframon.***.local]:10051 [ZBX_TCP_READ() timed out]
323160:20231027:123705.547 Active check configuration update started to fail
```

I suspect it has something to do with the Traefik Proxy. That something just won't get through - but i can't seem to put my finger on it.

Anyone here who has more experience?